# Django: relate userprofile to app models

Tags: python, django

myimages app:

models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.FileField()
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'image/add/$', views.ImageCreate.as_view(), name='image-add'),
```

views.py:

```
class ImageCreate (CreateView):
    model = Image
    fields = ['title', 'photo']
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user.userprofile
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

userprofiles/models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, related_name="profile", verbose_name=_(u'User'), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'Gender'), choices=GENDER) 
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='userprofiles/avatars', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u"Avatar"))
    completion_level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_(u'Profile completion percentage'))
    email_is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_(u'Email is verified'))
    personal_info_is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_(u'Personal info completed'))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name=_(u'User profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'User profiles')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"User profile: %s" % self.user.username

    def get_completion_level(self):
        completion_level = 0
        if self.email_is_verified:
            completion_level += 50
        if self.personal_info_is_completed:
            completion_level += 50
        return completion_level

    def update_completion_level(self):
        self.completion_level = self.get_completion_level()
        self.save()
        return
```

I am creating a website for people to upload images in Django

what should be added to the codes so that when a user of the page upload an image using the following generic view function, the database can save the owner and **relate the user as the owner to the image models**  here: `models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

error message when a user upload an image:
`'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile'`

Answer (score 0):

You can implemet this by overiding `form_valid` method. To get current user use `self.request.user`:

```
class ImageCreate (CreateView):
    model = Image
    fields = ['title', 'photo']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user.userprofile
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Related part of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).

Comment: thank you for you reply!!!! However, there is an error when i upload an image:  `Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: groupo>>": "Image.owner" must be a "UserProfile" instance.`

Comment: @JoseYu this is because `request.user` is not UserProfile instance. Try to change to this: `form.instance.owner = self.request.user.userprofile`. If this not help add to the question `UserProfile` model.

Comment: it still doesn't work, error message: 'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile' 
I have uploaded the userprofile model

Comment: @JoseYu you set `related_name=profile` for UserProfile, so you need to use it to get user's profile `form.instance.owner = self.request.user.profile`.

Comment: @ycsjose this mean current user doesnt have profile. Try to add profille frod admin page.

Comment: is it like this in admin.py :`from django.contrib import admin` 
`from .models import UserProfile` 
`admin.site.register(UserProfile)`
how come theres an error `Reverse for 'User profiles' not found. 'User profiles' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` ><